# Donation roll-ups are not working on Contact and Household

Tags: contact, npsp

I'm acessing salesforce with a NSPS org. I have add manually some donations through the contact page but those won't sum up on the rool up fields in the contacts neither on households.
I just confirmed and all the triggers are active, also the household settings are configured correctly.
Can some help figuring out what possible could be wrong?
Thanks in advanced
Best regards
Susana

Comment: Please provide more info that we can help!Sorry i never understood this

Comment: I'm using a nonprofit starter pack org
And i'm trying to update the fields about donation information and Donation Totals Based onsome donations. Those donations are marked as posted, the problem is that even with them marked as posted the fields are not updating properly. Is there any configuration needed in the object or in the settings that can calculate this fields?

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Nonprofit_Starter_Pack (there's an Entity Rel. Diagram but as it's a managed package I doubt we can ask for the body of triggers to be posted). Unless we have an user that worked with it (knows triggering conditions etc) I think best option will be to contact SF support...

Comment: @eyescream That seems like a good answer. I would suggest posting it as an answer to get more visibility for it.

Comment: If you don't get anyone here to help you out, you might want to try posting something to the [Nonprofit Salesforce.com Practitioners Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/npsf)

Answer (score 7):

I work at the Salesforce.com Foundation with the product manager of the Nonprofit Starter Pack.  Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Are you running the most recent version of Contacts and Organizations?  Rollups are only available in versions 2.x and above for both Contacts & Organizations, and Households.  You can find info on how to check your installed versions here:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TlVK3JBBCw&hd=1
2. Are you correctly displaying the summary rollup fields, are they on your page layout?
3. Have you added custom validation to your contact records? If you edit your contact and try to save, does the validation fail? When rollups are updated, any validation rules on your contact/household are run. Any contacts or households that fail those rules will not be updated with the rollups.
4. Are your opportunities in a closed/won stage? Is Posted a Closed/Won stage? Note: The name of the stage may not be 'Closed Won', it may be 'Posted', or some other variant. However, that stage has to be marked as closed/won in order for the opportunity to rollup. You can find out if your Stage value is closed/won by going to Setup->Customize->Opportunities->Fields->Stage and examine the 'Type' column for your Stage names.
5. When you go to the Opportunity Rollups tab, and manually run the rollups, are your values now correctly rolled up? If so, you may not have the opportunity trigger turned on. You can go to the Household Settings tab, select 'Roll Up Opps in Triggers', and then click 'Update the Households Settings'
6. Are you excluding any record types from rollups? You can check this by going to Household Settings and looking at the Opportunity Rollups Record Types section.
7. Do your Contacts all have a Household? Due to a bug in Salesforce, all Contacts MUST have a Household to be included as part of the rollups. This will hopefully be fixed in a future release.
8. Does your opportunity have an Opportunity Contact Role?  If not, you may need to turn on OCRs in the trigger. Go to your 'Contact Settings' tab, and check the box 'Enable Opportunity Contact Role Trigger', and click 'Update the Contacts & Organizations Settings.  You'll need to add an Opportunity Contact Role for any Opportunities that do not already have one.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The code is open source, by the way for those interested in digging into the trigger code: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Households

Comment: Awesome answer! Extremely informative. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: For us, the issue was related to #7; had a subset of `Opportunities` that had a `Primary Contact`, but were missing an `Account Name` (ie, `AccountId`). Thanks for this answer, just shy of 10 years later! 